# User validation failed: name: Cast to String failed for value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer, form-data

I am getting the above mentioned error on uploading more than one image. For one image it's working well but multiple images it's creating a problem. It shows validation error because on append two time images its also appending the name and lastname two times.
In the Front-end, I am using React and on the backend, I am using the Nodejs Express MongoDB and multer for image uploading.

Client#####

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
//binding
        this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            imgCollection: '',
            name: '',
            lastName: ''
        }
    }
// For the req body data on change on the text input
    handleChange(e) {
     this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })  
    }
//for image on change
    onFileChange(e) {
        this.setState({ imgCollection: e.target.files })
    }
    
//FOr form submition 
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        var formData = new FormData();
        for (const key of Object.keys(this.state.imgCollection)) {
            formData.append('imgCollection', this.state.imgCollection[key])
           formData.append('name', this.state.name )
           formData.append('lastName', this.state.lastName)
        }
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/upload-images", formData, {
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
            

       /*  fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/upload-images', { method: 'POST', body: formData  })
            .then(res => {
                res.json()
            console.log(res)}) */
        
    }


Server####
router.post('/upload-images', upload.array('imgCollection', 6), (req, res, next) => {
    const reqFiles = [];
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
        reqFiles.push(url + '/public/' + req.files[i].filename)
    }

    const user = new User({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        imgCollection: reqFiles,
        ...req.body
    });

    user.save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Done upload!",
            userCreated: {
                _id: result._id,
                imgCollection: result.imgCollection,
                name: result.name,
                lastName: result.lastName
            }
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err),
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
    })
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are appending formData multiple times using the same key. I don't think that would work. Generally, while adding multiple values to a field in formData - in order to append them as an array, here's what you need to do, add '[]' at the end of the key name. Here's a function you can try using to add multiple files:

```js
this.state.imgCollection.forEach(image => formData.append('imgCollection[]', image))
```

Comment: Sorry its giving me this error after the for each (this.state.imgCollection.forEach is not a function)

Comment: The Problem is Solved, I changed the following code                                 onFileChange=(e) => {
        this.setState({ imgCollection: [...this.state.imgCollection, ...e.target.files] })
    }

Comment: I am also editing the above-mentioned code